# How to calculate transformation from screen coordinates to isometric screen coordinates?

Tags: geometry, coordinates, trigonometry, projection, isometric

I've got the 2d coordinates:

```
0,   0
200, 0
200, 100
400, 100
400, 200
0,   200
```

The coordinates represent the following shape:
[image]

But I want to dynamically calculate the screen coordinate for each point transformed to isometric projection.
So I have the coordinate list of literally screen coordinates, and I want to generate screen coordinates from it, that represent the isometric 'version' of the shape.
Please note that I don't want to calculate the coordinates in the 'isometric world', I want to get the literal screen coordinates.
(rotated 45 degrees, and scaled vertically by 0.5)

[image]

*Where on the screen is each point with question marks?*
It's very likely that some coordinates would become negative, but that's fine. This can be logically solved by calculating an offset, so that the most left x coordinate is at zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> rotated 45 degrees, and scaled vertically by 0.5

This is affine transform:
shift by center of rotation (xc, yc) coordinates
rotation
shift back by xc and some yc (you might need another y-shift to align with screen edge)
scale by y-axis

```
   sq = Sqrt(2)/2   //Cos and Sin of 45
   x_new = xc + (x_old - xc) * sq - (y_old - yc) * sq
   y_new = 0.5 * (yc + (x_old - xc) * sq + (y_old - yc) * sq)
```

(probably you have to change sign combination in brackets from `(+-)(++)` to `(++)(-+)` depending on your coordinate system orientation)